# How to only return ArrayList of strings with minimum number of occurrences?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a `String[]`, `originalStringArray`, that has duplicates in them. So `{"dog","cat","dog","fish","dog","cat"}`.

I wanted to make a function that only returns the strings that occur exactly a certain number of times. For here, if I said 3, it would return "dog" but not "cat".

Here's my current code:

```
public ArrayList<String>  returnMultiples(String[] originalStringArray,int requiredCount){
    ArrayList<Integer> mCount = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(originalStringArray);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // Count occurrences in original string
    for(String item: originalStringArray){
        mCount.add(Collections.frequency(list,item));
    }

    // If frequency is equal to count, add to array list
    for(int i=0; i<mCount.size(); i++){
        if(mCount.get(i) == requiredCount){
            result.add(originalStringArray[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem I have is, I read somewhere that the Collections library is very slow and drag, and it also seems like that this method could be reduced using HashSets and tables. Unfortunately, I'm kind of at a loss on how to do that. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Show a citation. The Java Collections libraries are highly optimized. People who say they're slow usually aren't using them correctly. You're right. You want a Map<String, Integer> to solve this problem. In particular, if you want to maintain the original order of appearance, use an OrderedHashMap.

Comment: Performance doesn't really matter if you're handling small amounts of data in my opinion. When you're processing thousands or more elements then performance starts to matter, and even at that amount only a little bit. That being said you can't use a set because each set element has to be unique. I would insert each element and it's occurrence into a hashmap, during the initial array loop. Then you'll need to loop over the hashmap and grab the keys that match your occurrence criteria.

Comment: `Multiset` from the [Guava library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) is something designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @Gene well, to be frank, the citation would be one comment on another SO question. Not a very valid source. Thanks for the OrderHashMap idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sort of map will be required to carry this out. Here is an example written using HashMaps:

```
public ArrayList<String> returnMultiples(String[] array, int min){
    HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();//instantiate a new HashMap

    //loop through the array and count the occurrences of each different string in the array
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        String word = array[i];
        if(counts.containsKey(word))
            counts.put(word, counts.get(word) + 1);
        else
            counts.put(word, 1);
    }

    ArrayList<String> multiples = new ArrayList<String>();

    //check if any of the words occur >= min times. if so, add them to the returning list.
    for(String key : counts.keySet()){
        if(counts.get(key) >= min){
            multiples.add(key);
        }
    }

    return multiples;//return the list we just created of the desired strings
}
```

Depending on the length of the strings, the HashMap will be a little more efficient than using collections although the difference is mostly negligible.

Comment: Rather than using condition in the first `for` loop You can use `HashMap`'s [getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method as I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `HashMap` for this task.

Lets say your `HashMap` will contain count of occurences of given string, so it will be of type `HasMap<String,Integer>`

And now, lets iterate over your collection:

1. Get another string from your collection
2. Check if give string exists in HashMap (#contains)
3. If not exist, put new element with String key (hashMap.put(stringKey,1);
4. If it exists, put element with the same key, but increment the internal counter (hashMap.put(stringKey,hashMap.get(stringKey)+1)
5. Continue

Now you have hashmap contains exact number of occurences of given strings from your collections.

Fast lookup would be to create reverse `HashMap<Integer,String>` but there is a possibility that counts will duplicate and this wont work. To get the String that occurences matches the given string you will have to iterate over all keys of map, and return only those that occurences count matches your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm will return duplicates.

A HashSet *is* part of the Collections library, so no advantage for you there.

Your loop containing Collections.frequency is an O(n^2) algorithm. (for each String in originalStringArray Collections.frequency loops over the entire originalStringArray again).

You could do it with only a HashMap.

Increment an Integer in the map for each String in originalStringArray.

Remove all keys with a value different to requiredCount.

Add the map.keySet() to a new ArrayList, if you actually intended to return an ArrayList.

or map.keySet().toArray(String[map.size()]) if you want an array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `AVL Tree`, the premise would be that if you had let's say 1,000,000 items in your array it would take `1,000,000 steps` to go through that data structure. With an `AVL Tree` it would take `O(Log (1,000,000))` steps which is `== 6` steps, pretty neat. This would be a good approach if your data was dynamic, although you would have to optimize insertions.

With an AVL tree everything would be sorted, so you get `O(Log N)` time. Instead of transversing through an array like so for `N Steps`:

[image]

You could have something like so:

[image]

Where it checks the root and sees that the `Char` c is greater than the first `Char` in `dog`, and transverses left. Essentially cutting search time by `1/2` each step making it `O(Log N)` steps. You do have to keep the tree height balanced.

The nice thing about an `AVL Tree` is that your data is in sorted order all the time, since the tree needs to be balanced.

If the data doesn't change that often though and you don't need sorted data it would probably be better to use a `HashMap`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great detail on this. I've heard of a lot of different trees but never AVL before.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, efficient enough will be to use hash maps.

Shortest code that comes into my minds (and which uses HashMaps) will look like:

```
String[] filter(String[] collection, int requirement) {
    final HashMap<String, Integer> temp = new HashMap<>();

    for (String item : collection) {
        int current = temp.getOrDefault(item, 0);
        temp.put(item, ++current);
    }

    final Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = temp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
        if (entry.getValue() != requirement) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    return temp.keySet().toArray(new String[temp.size()]);
}
```

What can be used as follows:

```
final String[] array = new String[]{
    "dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "fish", "cat"
};

final String[] result = filter(array, 3);

for (String item : result) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

And generates output as expected:

> cat
>
> dog